# PIN sequence contains a repeated symbol

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Question: A typical PIN (personal identification number) is a sequence of any four symbols chosen from the $26$ letters in the alphabet and the ten digits. If all PINs are equally likely, what is the probability that a randomly chosen PIN contains a repeated symbol?

The Solution given: The number of PINs that contain at least one repeated symbol
$= 1,679,616 – 1,413,720 = 265896$

Thus, the probability that a randomly chosen PIN contains a repeated symbol is
$265,896 / 1,679,616 = 0.1583$

I understand this.
I attempted deriving the $265896$.

I got $269676$. Please correct.

My derivation:
All $4$ symbols are same = $\binom{4}{4} \times 36$

$3$ symbols are same = $\binom{4}{3} \times 36 \times 35$

$2$ symbols are same ($1$ pair) = $\binom{4}{2} \times 36 \times 35 \times 34$

$2$ pairs of $2$ symbols are same = $\binom{4}{2} \times 36 \times 35$

Total = $269676$

Answer (score 2):

Your final case is wrong.  To see this, ask yourself "When did I count the case of AABB?"  You counted it both when you selected the first two positions in the first step and selected that these should be the A's with the rest the B's as well as you counted it when you selected the last two positions in the first step and selected that these should be the B's when the rest should be the A's.

The correct amount for this case should have been half this, or equivalently written $\binom{3}{1}\times 36\times 35$, the count here for this case being derived either by dividing through by symmetry since we double-counted each case, or directly by saying that as the positions must come in pairs we merely need to figure out which of the three later positions is paired with the first position and then what character is used for each pair.

In doing so, your final total will be $36+4\times 36\times 35 + \binom{4}{2}\times 36\times 35\times 34+\binom{3}{1}\times 36\times 35 = 265896$

Of course, it is far easier and requires much less arithmetic to call this $36^4 - 36\times 35\times 34\times 33 = 265896$

Comment: Kindly explain how you counted directly                                               "we merely need to figure out which of the three later positions is paired with the first position and then what character is used for each pair."              Where have you selected the 'first position' in the first place

Comment: There are $36$ choices for what the first letter was (*and whatever other letter happened to match*).  There are $35$ choices for the other appearing letter was different than the first letter.  Without loss of generality, the first could be $A$ and the second $B$.  There are then three possible ways to pair one of the remaining positions with the first letter... be it AABB, or ABAB, or ABBA.  You can convince yourself there are no others (*and could have counted this directly with $\binom{3}{1}$*), giving the overall count.

Comment: @GaneshRam "*Where have you selected the 'first position' in the first place*"  We don't need to... there is an unambiguous *position* that is first... it is whatever appears at the front of the string of letters... in ABCD the first position is A.  In DCAB the first position is D.  There is no ambiguity in referring to that position as "first" and no need to "choose where" the first position is, merely what letter occupies it.  We could choose what letter occupies it before or after having chosen which other position is paired with it, it doesn't matter.